# How do I edit a discordjs embed but keep the new text I add, inside one code block?

Tags: discord.js

What I want:

```
nicembed1.data.fields[1].value = '[-] Accessing Pathway...';
    // Update the message using the edited original embed
    msg1.edit({ embeds: [nicembed1] });

nicembed1.data.fields[1].value = '[-] Accessing Pathway 2...';
    // Update the message using the edited original embed
    msg1.edit({ embeds: [nicembed1] });
```

The result i want is for these two message to show up in the same code block so it looks like:

```
[-] Accessing Pathway...
[-] Accessing Pathway 2...
```

I want it so be under each other in the same discord code block syntax. I dont want it to show up as two sperate code blocks like it has been.

I tried the following:

What I want:

```
nicembed1.data.fields[1].value = '[-] Accessing Pathway...';
    // Update the message using the edited original embed
    msg1.edit({ embeds: [nicembed1] });

nicembed1.data.fields[1].value = '[-] Accessing Pathway 2...';
    // Update the message using the edited original embed
    msg1.edit({ embeds: [nicembed1] });
```

The result i want is for these two message to show up in the same code block so it looks like:

```
[-] Accessing Pathway...
[-] Accessing Pathway 2...
```

I want it so be under each other in the same discord code block syntax. I dont want it to show up as two sperate code blocks like it has been.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to do this with embed fields and changing the field value you can do the following:

```
myembed.data.fields[0].value += '\nMy secondary text'
```

If you have the following or something similar:

```
const myembed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle('My Custom Embed')
    .setDescription('My description text here')
    .setFields({
        name: 'My field',
        value: 'My primary text',
    })
```

Comment: That just makes a new text under the code value instead of placing it inside the code block

Comment: What do you mean? using that it should display the same as the initial field value

Comment: Do you mind showing some screenshots of what you might mean? I do not think i am understanding quite what you mean since you are saying code block for field values which do not use code blocks so i am a little confused